# Text in android button is being cut

Tags: android, button

I have an issue concerning the dynamic change of Button sizes.
So, I defined 4 Buttons bellow the yellow progressbar (2 above, 2 below)  like shown in the image.

[image]

I have a class RatioButton that extend Button and in the method onMeasure() I redefine the size of the buttons to a certain ratio. The buttons above are RatioButton views and the buttons below are Button views. So far so good.

The problem, as you can see in the image, is that **the text in the upper buttons is cut**. What I want is that the text could adapt to the available space of the button. Can you help me?

Below is the RatioButton class:

```
public class RatioButton extends Button {

    public static final double RATIO = 280.0/260.0;

    public RatioButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RatioButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public RatioButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        int size = width > height ? height : width;
        setMeasuredDimension((int)(size*RATIO), size);
    }
}
```

Below is the layout definiton of the buttons (is the same for all four but the two below are just Button instead of RatioButton):

```
<myapp.pt.quiz.utils.RatioButton
                            style="@style/ChoiceButton"
                            android:id="@+id/game_screen_button3"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:text="This text is for layout testing"/>
```

This is the style ChoiceButton used in four buttons:

```
<style name="ChoiceButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/shape_choicebutton</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
</style>
```

And by the way, below is the drawable shape_choicebutton:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:left="1dp" android:top="3dp">
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
                    <corners android:radius="3dip"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp">
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
                    <corners android:radius="3dip"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:bottom="3dp" android:right="2dp">
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
                    <corners android:radius="3dip"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

</selector>
```

I hope the code helps to understand my doubt.

Comment: I think showing some code wouldn't hurt

Comment: I edited the question with some code.

Comment: Can you try setting padding for the text

Comment: @Yashasvi: Yes, I tried that but I'm not seeing any effect.